# Non-duplicate is marked as duplicate

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request

This question [How can I export & import firefox addons settings](https://superuser.com/questions/469104/hto-can-i-export-import-firefox-addons-settings?lq=1) is marked as duplicate of this [Software to export firefox addons](https://superuser.com/questions/218059/software-to-export-firefox-addons) but it is not, maybe it should be unmarked?

Comment: They're kind of close, but not identical. In my opinion, if the closed question's poster doesn't like the answers/they don't work it should be re-opened.